# Как сделать цикл для вывода последовательности значений в столбец?

Tags: excel, циклы, vba

Как вывести следующую последовательность значений в столбец I в цикле:

```
"0-100
100-200
200-300
300-400
400-0"
```

это данные вносимые вниз в столбец

Где: "0-" - константа, "100" - переменная, вводимая пользователем.

Может быть и так:

```
"0-300
300-600
600-0"
```

это данные вносимые вниз в столбец

```
Sub SumRows()

'переменные
Dim sSunRows As Single
Dim d As Single
Dim sAreaRows As Single
myPi = WorksheetFunction.Pi
d = Trim(Worksheets("Строка").Range("O2").Value)


'тело
sAreaRows = Application.InputBox("Введите max дефектуемый участок")
sSunRows = d * myPi / sAreaRows
sSunRows = WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(sSunRows, 0) - 2
Range("B14").EntireRow.Offset(1).Resize(sSunRows).Insert Shift:=xlDown
b = 14 + sSunRows + 1

For I = 14 To b
Range("I" & I & ":" & "J" & I).MergeCells = True
Next

Range("I" & "14" & ":" & "J" & "14").Value = "0-" & sAreaRows

For I = 15 To b
Range("I" & I & ":" & "J" & I).Value = sAreaRows & "-" & sAreaRows + sAreaRows
Next
End Sub
```

Застрял я в последних 4 строках

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: *400-0* - а это как?

Comment: *Застрял я в последних 4 строках* Наверное, не стоило объединять в одном операторе строковую конкатенацию и арифметическое сложение, а? ну или хотя бы расставить скобки...

Comment: @Akina, 400-0 означает закругление координат и конец окружности "-" это не минус а тире

Comment: ??? ну как бы окружность начинается от 0 градусов и заканчивается 360 градусами, хотя на ней это одна и та же точка...

Comment: @Akina, Извините, я конечно не эксперт в VBA, но это и есть ответ на вопрос, реально ли сделать такой цикл? Очень уж не хотел бы заморачиваться со стандартными числами

Comment: @Akina, по нашей специфике работы, нас интересует длинна окружности, а не то что она 360 градусов, и нас интересует участок его длинны от 400 до нуля. Чтобы было понятно в градусах нас интересует участок условно от 300 до 360 (0) градусов :-)

Comment: Градусы - это условно. Если Вы разметили окружность на 500 делений, то последнюю делайте не 400-0, а 400-500. Ну то есть на экране пишите что хотите, а вот при расчётах используйте именно такие границы.

Comment: @Akina, так, это я понял) но я элементарно не могу сообразить как это сделать циклом) очень уж я новичок в VBA

Comment: Удалите ```Range("I" & "14" & ":" & "J" & "14").Value = "0-" & sAreaRows```. Следующий цикл замените на ```For i = 14 To b: Range("I" & i & ":" & "J" & i).Value = (sAreaRows * (i - 14)) & "-" & sAreaRows * (i - 13): Next```

Comment: @Akina, офигеть!!! это работает!) Может еще подскажете как этому толково научиться), ваш цикл прекрасно работает в том, который объединяет ячейки, именно так я и хотел) Спасибо Вам огромное

Comment: @Александр Так потрассируйте код. Откройте Locals. Добавьте отдельные выражения в Watch. И посмотрите, как меняются значения переменных.

Answer (score 0):

Такое чувство, что ваша проблема заключается в том, как правильно собрать алгоритм вывода последовательности. От нуля и до конца массива с шагом sAreaRows.

Где: sAreaRows - значение, определяемое пользователем.

Попробую угадать:

```
Dim sLeft: sLeft = 0
For I = 15 To b
    Dim sRight: sRight = sLeft + sAreaRows
    If I = b Then sRight = 0
    Range("I" & I).Value = sLeft & "-" & sRight
    sLeft = sLeft + sAreaRows
Next
```

И ещё, вам достаточно заполнить левую ячейку среди объединённых, т.е. столбец I.